# Force eloquent to use mutators during serialization

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, mutators

Is there a way to force eloquent to use mutators when serializing data? I am currently converting my app to use vue.js and several fields are computed within the model, which I need to be included, in the serialized data.

[Eloquent\Model - make toArray() utilize mutators](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/153)

I understand why Taylor does not honour mutators but is there a way to override this behaviour?

Comment: what version of laravel are you using ... do you mean accessors (get mutator)? in modern versions the serialized output uses the accessors/mutators

Answer (score 2):

Before returning the model, you can do this

```
$model->setAppends(['mutator_1', 'mutator_2']);
return $model->toArray();
```

if you want to use it on a collection :

```
$collection->each(function($model) { $model->setAppends(...); });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define which getters should be serialized like this:

```
protected $appends = ['is_admin'];
```

More info: [Appending Values to JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json)

Answer (score 0):

this is working for me on laravel 8 :

```
$model->setAppends($model->getMutatedAttributes())->toArray();
```

all mutated attributes are included in the serialized results with the code above