# Add attribute append on collection at run time

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, attributes, append

```
 class Student extends Model
 {
    .... some code here

    public function getGroupAttribute()
    {
        if($this->group == 1)
           return  'Group A';
        else
           return 'No Group';
    }
 }
```

I know there is function setAppends() but that one is for a single model ONLY. 
and I also know the static way which is define the $appends variable at class as :

```
protected $appends = ['group']; // but this is not changable if I did it like this.
```

How to achieve set $append at run time on a controller ?

```
  //inside controller

  public function getStudent()
  {
      Student::whereIn('id',[1,4,10,21])->get(); // I want to set the $appends value here
  }
```

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47692755/3226121)

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to use `pluck` ?

```
Student::whereIn('id',[1,4,10,21])->pluck('group');
```

**Based on** [Retrieving A List Of Column Values](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#retrieving-results)